# Not Creating Excel file in my solutions temp folder

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

On a button click I am creating an Excel file in a "Temp" folder on the server, and writing data to it. This is working on my local machine, but when I tried it from the virtual directory it is not creating any file in the "Temp" folder.

My application is in .NET 3.5 with IIS.

Answer (score 1):

Does your IIS user on the server have write access to the temp folder? Normally the IIS accounts are very locked down to prevent a hacker gaining access to IIS from damaging the rest of the system.

Comment: I guess it's a security issue too, just make sure you are giving the write access to the right accounts.